# Table locking in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, ado.net, locking

is there a simple way to implement table locking in ADO.NET (without beeing dependend on a specific DBMS-feature)? I'm currently using TransactionScopes, but I'm not quite sure, whether they lock the table…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, TransactionScope will not usually do a table lock; it may do row, page, key-range, table etc **as the db sees fit**.

For specific locking mechanisms I would expect to have to use vendor-specific mechanisms, such as different SQL hints.

Comment: Is there a recommended way how to do something like this: Insert a new row to the table -> retrieve newly created primary key (Identity). I currently rely on @@IDENTITY, as SCOPE_IDENTITY is not supported in SQL Server Compact…

Comment: @MFH does it support the OUTPUT clAuse with INSERT?

Comment: @Marc I'd say so, but I can't figure out the syntax :( How can I use the clause? I have "INSERT INTO ACL (Username, Password, IsAdmin) OUTPUT INSERTED.ACL_ID VALUES ('TEST3', 'PASSWORD', 0). But I get a Token-Error (OUTPUT) by the Visual Studio Database Queryer…

Comment: @MFH then maybe it doesn't :(